# SAS - rolling N months

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I am looking to use a factor based on YRMON (YYYY:MM) from a static list of factors that are based on the last 12 months (rolling forward every month)

I have a static dataset that looks this simple (see below):
I basically need to create a format that changes the yrmon to a rolling 13 months that I can stamp on the factor (for calculation needs) based on the yrmon.

```
yrmon   facto
DATE00  1.00000 
DATE01  0.99944 
DATE02  0.99907 
DATE03  0.99907 
DATE04  0.99889 
DATE05  0.99799 
DATE06  0.99659 
DATE07  0.99500 
DATE08  0.99296 
DATE09  0.99100 
DATE10  0.85000 
DATE11  0.78000 
DATE12  0.34900
```

Example Data before/after:

```
YRMON     PAYAMT         PAYAMT_AFTER
2020:10   $100.00        $34.90
2020:08   $100.00        $85.00
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
/*Create macro dates*/
%let to_date = %sysfunc(date());
%let paydt = %sysfunc(intnx(month,&to_date, -(0)));
%let payday = %eval(&paydt. -1);


%let chirodt12 = %sysfunc(intnx(month,&payday,-0), date9.);
%let chirodt11 = %sysfunc(intnx(month,&payday,-1), date9.);
%let chirodt10 = %sysfunc(intnx(month,&payday,-2), date9.);
%let chirodt9 = %sysfunc(intnx(month,&payday,-3), date9.);
%let chirodt8 = %sysfunc(intnx(month,&payday,-4), date9.);
%let chirodt7 = %sysfunc(intnx(month,&payday,-5), date9.);
%let chirodt6 = %sysfunc(intnx(month,&payday,-6), date9.);
%let chirodt5 = %sysfunc(intnx(month,&payday,-7), date9.);
%let chirodt4 = %sysfunc(intnx(month,&payday,-8), date9.);
%let chirodt3 = %sysfunc(intnx(month,&payday,-9), date9.);
%let chirodt2 = %sysfunc(intnx(month,&payday,-10), date9.);
%let chirodt1 = %sysfunc(intnx(month,&payday,-11), date9.);
%let chirodt0 = %sysfunc(intnx(month,&payday,-12), date9.);

%put  chirodt12 &chirodt12.;
%put  chirodt11 &chirodt11.;
%put  chirodt10 &chirodt10.;
%put  chirodt9 &chirodt9.;
%put  chirodt8 &chirodt8.;
%put  chirodt7 &chirodt7.;
%put  chirodt6 &chirodt6.;
%put  chirodt5 &chirodt5.;
%put  chirodt4 &chirodt4.;
%put  chirodt3 &chirodt3.;
%put  chirodt2 &chirodt2.;
%put  chirodt1 &chirodt1.;
%put  chirodt0 &chirodt0.;

filename ibnr "/path/to/file/file.txt";
data ibnr;
infile ibnr dlm='09'X dsd missover firstobs = 2;
informat month $6. factor 7.5;
input month factor;
run;

data ibnr;
    set ibnr;
    if month = 'DATE12' then yrmon = put("&chirodt12"D, yymmc7.);
    else if month = 'DATE11' then yrmon = put("&chirodt11"D, yymmc7.);
    else if month = 'DATE10' then yrmon = put("&chirodt10"D, yymmc7.);
    else if month = 'DATE09' then yrmon = put("&chirodt9"D, yymmc7.);
    else if month = 'DATE08' then yrmon = put("&chirodt8"D, yymmc7.);
    else if month = 'DATE07' then yrmon = put("&chirodt7"D, yymmc7.);
    else if month = 'DATE06' then yrmon = put("&chirodt6"D, yymmc7.);
    else if month = 'DATE05' then yrmon = put("&chirodt5"D, yymmc7.);
    else if month = 'DATE04' then yrmon = put("&chirodt4"D, yymmc7.);
    else if month = 'DATE03' then yrmon = put("&chirodt3"D, yymmc7.);
    else if month = 'DATE02' then yrmon = put("&chirodt2"D, yymmc7.);
    else if month = 'DATE01' then yrmon = put("&chirodt1"D, yymmc7.);
    else if month = 'DATE00' then yrmon = put("&chirodt0"D, yymmc7.);
run;

/*format for later use to stamp on factor for calculations*/
data chrofact (keep = fmtname label start type hlo);
retain fmtname 'chfact' type 'C';
set ibnr end = lastrec;
start=yrmon;
label = factor;
output;
if lastrec then do;
start='XXX' ;
hlo = 'O';
label = '0';
output;
end;
run;

proc format cntlin = chrofact;
run;
```

This gives me what I want; but I'm just sure there's a simpler method out there

Comment: please post your efforts, not just your thoughts, and use them to pinpoint where you think this is not working well.

Comment: Why are you making macro variables if you are just going to use the value in a data step?  Why not just call the INTNX() function in the data step itself?

Comment: I feell like we're solving the wrong problem here, can you explain your use case or are you set on using this methodology for your problem.

Comment: I ultimately have a static list of factors that the factors themselves don't change.
I need to use these factors to stamp the factor based on the Year Month.  that is always changing each month, rolling forward a month.

Comment: Please review the guidelines on how to post a question [ask].

Comment: What does 'stamp the factor based on the year month' mean? Exactly.

Comment: Data that updates monthly has a yrmon field as well as a measure field (payamt)  based on the yrmon we are calculating a $ amount based on the 'factor' which is based on the yrmon.

Example:

2020:10     $100.00    
2020:08     $100.00
Calculated based on the 'factors for the yrmon' this would then be
2020:10     $34.90 (based on multiplying $100 *  0.34900; the factor for 2020:10) 
2020:08     $85.00 (based on multiplying $100  * 0.85000; the factor for 2020:08)

Comment: `Example: 2020:10 $100.00 2020:08 $100.00 Calculated based on the 'factors for the yrmon' this would then be 2020:10 $34.90 (based on multiplying $100 * 0.34900; the factor for 2020:10` the logic here isn't clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting a text value to a SAS date value is an INPUT operation (i.e. INFORMAT), not a PUT operation (i.e. FORMAT).

Instead consider creating a lookup table that maps a **literal** string `"DATE<nn>"` to a SAS date value corresponding to some predetermined base date.

Example

Decode the `<nn>` portion of the string literal and apply it in a call to `INTNX`.  Use the output as the basis of CNTLIN for INFORMAT or as a lookup table LEFT JOINED or HASH JOINED to some other data set containing string literals "DATE"

```
data have;
length yrmon $6 facto 8.;
input yrmon   facto;
basedate = today();
month = input(substr(yrmon,5),2.);
month_ago = 12-month;
ago_date = intnx('month', basedate, -month_ago);
format ago_date yymmdd10.;
datalines;
DATE00  1.00000 
DATE01  0.99944 
DATE02  0.99907 
DATE03  0.99907 
DATE04  0.99889 
DATE05  0.99799 
DATE06  0.99659 
DATE07  0.99500 
DATE08  0.99296 
DATE09  0.99100 
DATE10  0.85000 
DATE11  0.78000 
DATE12  0.34900 
;
```

Image of output data set in viewer

[image]

Comment: Thank you; that worked perfect. Definitely a lot cleaner code than all those macro dates.